# Существует ли приоритет хуков клавиш?

Tags: windows, winapi

Я знаю, что можно зарегистрировать хук в системе, а далее при перехвате либо проглотить сообщение, либо кинуть дальше.

Однако, можно ли управлять тем, каким по счету в цепочке будет мой хук?

Такой вопрос возник по тому, что есть приложение, которое имеет hotkey, который отрабатывает пока приложение не в фокусе и есть второе приложение, которое реагирует на кнопки но пока находится в фокусе. Так вот, первое приложение всегда ловит сообщение раньше.

Answer (score 0):

Хуки и обработка горячих клавиш - это разные вещи. Для глобальных комбинаций есть функция [`RegisterHotKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey). Для обработки клавиш внутри приложения есть разные варианты, однако они тоже не включают хуки. И, конечно, зарегистрированные глобальные комбинации клавиш имеют приоритет над уровнем приложения.